# Почему пустая строка это и не true и не false?

Tags: javascript

Я столкнулся с такой ситуацией, что пустая строка это и не тру и не фалс

```
'' === true // false
'' === false // false
```

есть ли какое-то объяснение этому ?

Comment: потому что это строка, а не булевая переменная?

Comment: @teran Я понимаю что это не булеан переменная, но ведь массив, к примеру, тоже не булеан, но в проверке он тру `if ([]) console.log(123) // 123` а если `if ('') console.log(123) // ничего`

Comment: Как ни странно, потому, что _пустая строка это и не тру и не фалс_

Comment: _массив, к примеру, тоже не булеан, но в проверке он тру if ([])_  так и в вопросе у тебя на `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете оператор сравнения `===`, который учитывает в том числе и тип данных операндов. И поскольку в с одной стороны у вас строковая переменная, а с другой булевая, результат будет отрицательный. Как и например для `1 === true` или `0 === false`.

При обычном сравнении `==` за счет неявного приведения  типов вы получите иной результат.

```js
console.log( '' === false) ;
console.log( '' == false);
```

При обычном сравнении как `false` вычисляются само  `false`, `0`, `"", ''`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`. Все остальное равно `true`, как и упомянутый вами `[]`.

Повторюсь, при сравнении `===` имеет значение равенство типов данных. В этом и есть вся суть данного оператора.